# How to dismiss alert view when application is put in background?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

If I get an alert in my application and if I put application in background and press application icon to enter the application, a splash screen is displayed and then the alert pop up. Why splash screen appears?
And if alert is not present and I put application in background and press application icon to enter the application, splash screen is not displayed.

Answer (score 6):

First you have to make the `UIAlertView` a property in your class.
In your AppDelegate Class you can implement the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` Method in wich you can put something like this:

```
[yourViewController.yourAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
```

This should dismiss the alert if your app enters the background.
Hope this helps!

Comment: if i have multiple alertview, how can i close them? Any idea? @pmk

Answer (score 1):

The splash screen is as @akshay1188 mentions, is the `Default.png` in your project file. The reason for it being displayed, based on my best assumption, is because the OS has not managed to take a screenshot of your App before you go back to it. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8391776/768510) to a StackOverflow question where it was discussed.

As for the `UIAlertView`, @pKoul's anwser got my upvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dismiss all AlertViews programmatically you have to Remember a Reference to the currently shown Alterviews. I recommend a Singleton class where you ask for an AlertView and wich saves a Reference to the AlertView.

then you could use the

```
`- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`
```

in your AppDelegate and call a Function on the Singleton Class, wich itself calls

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

at all Alertviews.

Comment: Now alert is not displayed when I enter the application but splash screen does.

Comment: I guess you Implemented as I recommended you? If yes: How do you show your Splashscreen?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the notification posted UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification in any class that needs some cleanup before entering bg. **Do not forget to remove the observer in dealloc.**

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(cleanup:) 
                                                 name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification 
                                               object: nil]
```

Answer (score 0):

The splash screen is actually the launch image that you might be using as Default.png