# understanding Launch images iPhone/iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios

As suggested by Apple I have provided a launch image which equals to my home page iOS app.

At the moment I am testing on the iPhone simulator and I wanted to know if the same happens on real devices.

Everything works fine, however when I am in pages other than home page and I exit from application by pressing the button, then when I enter again, the launch images shows for an instant, and then suddenly the last viewed pages appears.

I wonder how can I avoid this "flickering" of pages. I don't know if this is important, but I am using Storyboards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the intended behaviour if you immediately start the app again. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8391776/768510) to another Stack Overflow question on a similar matter.

To explain, the `Default.png` image is used when the OS is unable to take a screen shot of your last view state. Giving the OS a little longer to screen shot the app will prevent the `Default.png` being used. This is done so that the device does not just show a black screen, followed by your app popping in.

I am not aware of functionality to see if the OS has finished taking a screen shot. If this was possible you could place a `UIImageView` on top of your last view and do a more subtle fade out one you have control again.

Comment: It seems that this is happening on iOS simulator only, during development on a real device I never experienced such issue (yet!).

Comment: I experience it frequently on my first model 3GS, the performance of the newer devices might make it unnoticeable, best of luck!